# Supremum of a sequence of real numbers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, supremum-and-infimum

Let $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of real numbers whose terms are defined as follows :

$b_1 :=x+\frac{22}{13^2} -\frac{2}{13}y$, $b_2 :=x+\frac{22}{14^2} -\frac{2}{14}y$ and so on, where $x \in \mathbb R$ and $ y \in \mathbb N$ and $y \geq 2$ is arbitrarily fixed.

I need to calculate $\text{Sup}_{n \in \mathbb N}(b_n)$.

Claim: $\text{Sup}_{n \in \mathbb N}(b_n) =x$.

Attempt : It's not difficult to guess by inspection that  the sequence is strictly increasing. For that purpose it's enough to check that the function $f(m)= \frac{22}{m^2}-\frac{2y}{m}$ is strictly decreasing for $m \geq 13$. For this we need that $2m^2 > 20m +11$ for all $m \geq 13$.

Once we have shown  that the sequence is increasing we note that the terms $\frac{22}{m^2}-\frac{2y}{m}$ goes to $0$ as $m$ increases (Here is the place where I need more rigour). Therefore the sequence has supremum $x$

Please correct me if the above argument is not correct. Also it will be valuable to me if someone points out a more rigorous solution.

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Comment: Isn’t the function decreasing ?

Comment: @VivaanDaga, yes I have mentioned that $f(m)$ is strictly decreasing for $m \geq 13$.

Comment: For an increasing sequence, the limit (in this case $x$) is at the same time the supremum. This is a well-known fact and normally you wouldn't need to prove it. If you really need a proof, you can put something up with $\epsilon-\delta$ logic. For example, convergent sequence is bounded, so it has a supremum, call it $\overline{x}$ and then prove that $x=\overline{x}$ by proving $x\le\overline{x}$ ($b_n\le\overline{x}$ so $x=\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n\le\overline{x}$) and $x\ge\overline{x}$: if $x<\overline{x}$ then some $b_n>x$ ($x$ smaller than supremum) and so all $b_m\ge b_n>x$ for $m\ge n$ etc.

Comment: Does my answer answer your question ?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof that for large enough $m$ , $22/m^2- 2y/m$  is arbitrarily close to $0$ . It suffices to prove this for  $1/m$ since if $1/m$ approaches $0$ then $2y/m$ approaches $0$ and $22/m^2$  approaches $0$ .  So we have to prove for all $\epsilon>0$ there exists a natural N such that for for all $m>N$ we have $1/m<\epsilon$ (Since $m$ is always postive ) rearranging we can see that picking $N>1/\epsilon$(Which exists thanks to the Archimedean property )
concludes the proof .

Form here it’s easy to conclude that $x$ is the supremum .